# Error in accessing database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am accessing a service based database by using the following connection string

```
static string appath = Library_Records.Program.app_path;

string connectionstring = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=appath;Integrated Security = true;User Instance = True";
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

 static string dbfiles = null;
 internal static string app_path
 {
     get { return dbfiles = "|Datadirectory|\\5700.mdf"; }
 }
```

Library_Records:namespace, Program is the class name containing `Main()`

When I call `connection.Open()`, it gives the following error

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file appath failed. A
>   database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

`5700` is my database with `.mdf` extension. How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are never automatically replaced with values in strings, so `AttachDbFilename=appath;` will not work.

You should do something like:

```
string connectionstring = 
    string.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True", appath);

connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
```

Comment: It worked thankyou sir Now if i create a setup file(.exe) then will the database be accessible on any other computer because i first created a setup in which AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Sarao\Documents\prjs\Library_Records\Library_Records\5700.mdf and when i run it on the other computer it said that database is not accessible followed by path

Comment: As long as you copy your database file to another computer together with your program - it should work.